# How to stop legs in a walk cycle?

Tags: flash, animation

I have an animated graphic symbol on the main timeline and its legs animated on the sub level.

Yo can see here:
http://mementocosmicum.web44.net/test.php

All legs are on the same layer and their animation is frame by frame.
On the main timeline animation is motion tween.

How can I stop legs animation once the main symbol stops moving from left to right?

I tried  this (on actions layer - on the corresponding frame) on the main timeline and also on the sub timeline:

```
stop();
```

But it doesn't work. Legs continues to animate.

Comment: I am going to venture to guess that you haven't accurately described your movie clip structure or the type of symbols you used.  MovieClip Symbols and Graphic Symbols behave very differently in terms of their relationship to the timeline.  MovieClips are _independent_ of their parent timeline, while Graphic Symbols are _dependent_ on their parent timeline.  Based on that, it is very easy to tell where the issue truly lies.

Comment: Also, just a side note, since you are doing timeline based animation, and not using ActionScript based, `Tween` class animation,, I'm gonna have to say that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (SO). SO is about programming related questions.  Just giving you a heads up.

Comment: @SlyRaskal, Thanks for your explanation, but all my symbols are graphic symbols, not movie clips. I placed a picture of legs timeline on the linked page. Could you see, pls. I think this is question about coding, because there is no way to stop sub animation without as. To be honest, I think so, but I'm not sure

Comment: Again, Graphic Symbols are _dependent_ on their parent timeline.  So if you have a graphic symbol that has 20 frames and is set to "Play Once", and it is placed on a timeline that has 10 frames, _only_ 10 frames of the grahpic symbol's 20 frames will play and it will automatically stop.  This is the nature of a graphic symbol.  Something isn't adding up here.

Comment: Have you embedded any MovieClips inside of your Graphic Symbols?

Comment: @SlyRaskal, no, I have no any movie clip in the file.